# OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory

Tags: python, django

When I have installed django-registration-redux  and try to run  `python manage.py syncdb` I get following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_registration_redux-1.2-py2.7.egg/registration/migrations'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 93, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 176, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 93, in load_disk
    for name in os.listdir(directory):
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_registration_redux-1.2-py2.7.egg/registration/migrations'
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/issues/103  helps me.
Used python setup.py develop to reinstall registration redux

Answer (score 0):

This  https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/issues/43 might give you some direction.

**Update**
I was having the same issue, it is an open bug - [see this](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/issues/103).
Delete the django registration redux egg from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` and reinstall using `python setup.py develop`. This should work.

Comment: Thanks sg491.But I have little idea on what to do